# Chown doesn't work on files in an external drive?

Tags: linux, mount, chown

I first mounted an WD Elements drive by

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/elements
```

Then, created a test file under the mounted drive by

```
touch test
```

And got

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 zhijia zhijia  0 2013-03-09 02:53 test
```

Then I tried to change its owner by

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql test
```

But the owner didn't change at all. What's the reason? How to solve it?

Below is the `mount`:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lib/ureadahead/debugfs type debugfs (rw,relatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/zhijia/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=zhijia)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/Elements type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/elements type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

Comment: Which file system is on the drive?

Answer (score 3):

To linux there is no difference on external/internal hard drive, all that matters is the filesystem. Forget about chown and chmod, these only work if the filesystem supports unix style permissions, and as you've found out, Windows filesystems do not.

Comment: you mean this is a windows filesystem ?

Comment: fuseblk is just how an ntfs partition is reported via the "mount" command

Comment: Then how could solve this issue? reformat the external drive?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mount, use ntfs-3g:
sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/elements
you may need to install ntfs-3g with apt-get or the like (yum).